# Keras weighted merge

Tags: machine-learning, merge, neural-network, theano, keras

I am trying to compute a weighted output from multiple parallel models using Keras' `Merge` layer. I'm using `Theano` backend.

I have `L` parallel models `(Ci)`. Each of their output layer is a k-sized softmax.

There is one model `(N)`, its output is a L-sized softmax.

Here is what I have so far:

Parallel models `(Ci)` each with k dimension in the output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(K, activation='softmax', W_regularizer=l2(0.001),init='normal'))
```

The weighing model `(N)`, output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(L, activation='softmax', W_regularizer=l2(0.001), init='normal'))
```

The merger is as follows:

```
model.add(Merge(layers=model_group,
                mode=lambda model_group: self.merge_fun(model_group, L),
                output_shape = (None, k)))
```

where "model_group" is a (L+1)-length list `[N, C1, C2, ..., CL]`, and `merge_fun`'s signature is:

```
def merge_fun(self, model_group, L):
```

Mathematically, I would like the output of the merged layer to be a weighted sum:

> *out = N[1]x([C11, C12, C13, .., C1k]) + N[2]x([C21, C22, C23, ..., C2k]) + ... + N[L]x([CL1, CL2, CL3, ..., CLk])*,

where out is a vector of size `k`

How can I use the Merge layer to achieve this ?

I know that the magic would probably have to happen in the 'merge_fun', but I am not sure how to perform matrix algebra in Keras. The tensor parameters don't have a "shape" parameter - they have a `keras_shape = (None, K or L)` - but I am not sure how to combine parallel models' output into a matrix.

I tried using a local evaluation of the following expressions:

```
K.concatenate([model_group[1], model_group[2]], axis=0)*model_group[0]
```

and

```
model_group[0] * K.concatenate([model_group[1], model_group[2]], axis=0)
```

both of which didn't throw an error, so I can't use this as a guide. After the multiplication, the result returned did not have the `keras_shape` variable, so I'm not sure what the shape of the result is.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: here a simple way to operate a learnable weighted average: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595660/weighted-average-custom-layer-weights-dont-change-in-tensorflow-2-2-0/62595957#62595957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I advise you is to use a [functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/) and use this is in a following manner:

1. Define the `L` output models:

   ```
   softmax_1 = Dense(K, activation='softmax', ...))(input_to_softmax_1)
   softmax_2 = Dense(K, activation='softmax', ...))(input_to_softmax_2)
   ...
   softmax_L = Dense(K, activation='softmax', ...))(input_to_softmax_L)
   ```
2. Define the merge softmax:

   ```
   merge_softmax= Dense(L, activation='softmax', ...)(input_to_merge_softmax)
   merge_softmax = Reshape((1, L))(merge_softmax)
   ```
3. Merge and reshape the bag of `L` models:

   ```
   bag_of_models = merge([softmax_1, ..., softmax_L], mode = 'concat')
   bag_of_models = Reshape((L, K))(bag_of_models)
   ```
4. Compute the final merged softmax:

   ```
   final_result = merge([bag_of_models, merge_softmax], mode = 'dot', dot_axes = [1, 2])
   final_result = Reshape((K, ))(final_result)
   ```

Of course - depending on your topology - different tensor might be the same (e.g. input to different softmaxes). I tested this on my machine but due to extensive refactoring - I might made mistake - so if you fin one - please inform me.

The solution with `Sequential` is much less clear and a little bit cumbersome - but if you want one - please write in the comment so I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the feedback. I haven't had a chance to work on it yet. I will update (hopefully soon) with feedback.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay. So after I construct the merge (Sequential) model, I access the output layer directly (via name). This corresponds to your "merge_softmax". I verified that it was a "Dense" type. But when I call reshape as in: Reshape((1, L))(merge_outlayer), I get a "not a Keras tensor". Is there an option I am missing here ?

Comment: Just for clarification: The N-is built as its own (Sequential) model. And each of the Ci's are built as their individual (Sequential) models. Just in case if accessing - and merging - layers across Model instances matters

Comment: It seems that your method works, with some modifications: after merging _Ci's_, I had to wrap them into an `Input()`. Also after the 'dot' multiplication, I had to re-wrap the tensor in an Input - using functional notation `final_result = Input(tensor=Reshape((num_classes,))(final_result))`. The shape output is as expected, and the model runs (with some loss decrease.. ). But now after I save the model, I cannot load it again.