# How can I add trainable weights while concatenating layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation, weighted-average

I am trying to concatenate two layers in such a way that layers are assigned trainable weights while concatenating. The idea behind this is that my model can determine which layer should be given higher weights while concatenating.

I have read this code `[https://stackoverflow.com/a/62595957/12848819][1]`

```
class WeightedAverage(Layer):

def __init__(self, n_output):
    super(WeightedAverage, self).__init__()
    self.W = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.uniform(shape=[1,1,n_output], minval=0, maxval=1),
        trainable=True) # (1,1,n_inputs)

def call(self, inputs):

    # inputs is a list of tensor of shape [(n_batch, n_feat), ..., (n_batch, n_feat)]
    # expand last dim of each input passed [(n_batch, n_feat, 1), ..., (n_batch, n_feat, 1)]
    inputs = [tf.expand_dims(i, -1) for i in inputs]
    inputs = Concatenate(axis=-1)(inputs) # (n_batch, n_feat, n_inputs)
    weights = tf.nn.softmax(self.W, axis=-1) # (1,1,n_inputs)
    # weights sum up to one on last dim

    return tf.reduce_sum(weights*inputs, axis=-1) # (n_batch, n_feat)
```

but this one performs the weighted average of the layers. Please help. Let me know if you more questions. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind. If one layer has greater influence on y, the weights of that layer will automatically be weighted higher. The only usecase that comes in my mind is that you want to define that the weights of layer 1 are x2 important than the weights of layer 2

Comment: @MichaelJanz the use case would very similar to the one explained in this research paper [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03500) by Xiaojie Qi, Yindi Zhao. In the paper, the authors have added a weight mechanism for concatenation. e.g., X' = concat(a*X1, X2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a weighted sum (not an average), to similar effect

```
class WeightedSum(layers.Layer):
    """A custom keras layer to learn a weighted sum of tensors"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WeightedSum, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape=1):
        self.a = self.add_weight(name='alpha',
                                 shape=(1),
                                 initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(0.5),
                                 dtype='float32',
                                 trainable=True,
                                 constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(
                                     max_value=1, min_value=0))
        super(WeightedSum, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, model_outputs):
        return self.a * model_outputs[0] + (1 - self.a) * model_outputs[1]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a functional model :

```
W = tf.Variable(1 ,trainable=True )
input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))
input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))

x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(input1)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(input2)

#merge two layers (x1 x2)and add weight to a layer of them
concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([ w * x1 , x2 ])
```