# How to create a linear combination layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to merge several models as a linear combination of their outputs with trainable coefficients. Is it possible to write a custom layer that returns something like this in Keras?

```
alpha1 * out1 + alpha2 * out2 + alpha3 * out3 + ...
```

Model outputs have dimensions (batch_size, n, n, 1).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62595957/10375049